# How do you map subclass properties to columns in Table per Hierarchy?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

**Note:** I think this is technically still code-first but I have an existing database as well so I'm not generating models or the database on the fly (no .edmx).

I have a TPH situation where the subclasses have fields specific to them.  I have an `EntityTypeConfiguration` defined for the base class.  **How do I map the subclass-specific fields to columns in my database table?**

```
public class Letter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class A : Letter
{
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}

public class B : Letter
{
    public ComplexType description { get; set; }
}



public class LetterMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Letter>
{
    HasKey...
}
```

This is EF 4.1.

Edit:

I've implemented the solution Eranga suggested [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231173/how-do-you-map-subclass-properties-to-columns-in-table-per-hierarchy/7231294#7231294).  My problem now is that two subclasses map different values to the same column. (A third subclass doesn't populate the column at all which is why I can move the property up a level).

> (590,6) : error 0019: Each property name in a type must be unique.
>   Property name 'Description_Title' was already defined.

For example:

B.description.title maps to the column "Description_Title"

while

C.description.shortTitle maps to the same column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `Letter` class abstract

```
public abstract class Letter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class LetterMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Letter>
{
    public LetterMap()
    {
        HasKey(l => l.Id);

        //assuming discriminator column is "Type"
        Map<A>(a => a.Requires("Type").HasValue<byte>(1));
        Map<B>(b => b.Requires("Type").HasValue<byte>(2));
    }
}

public class BMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<B>
{
    public LetterMap()
    {
          HasOptional(b => b.description)
            WithMany()
            HasForeignKey(b=> b.descriptionId);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my `DbContext` class do I need to `Add()` each subclass map to the `Configurations` in addition to the base class map?  e.g. `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BMap());`

Comment: @Jeff If you have `B` specific configuration then you need to add. In your example you don't need to add `AMap` because EF will use conventions to figure out `A` mappings

Comment: Thanks.  I've added some detail to the question.  Implementing what you suggest brings up another issue for me.